# Modifying out of the box CSS for Sharepoint 2010

Tags: css, sharepoint, bootstrap-4

So i'm adding Bootstrap to my Sharepoint 2010 site. I'm dealing with the issues as they come but one thing I can't find any information on is what class the 'hover' and 'active' class is being used for the Global Navigation. I've attached a picture so you can see what i'm trying to fix. You can see on the second nav bar in the picture, the "transparent box" around the button isn't extending to the bottom of the navigation element. I can't find the class that controls this so I can fix it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The css class for that should be just:
`.ms-siteactionsmenuhover`

Comment: I figured it was for the site actions button in particular but it was happening to all the global nav buttons. I actually figured out, for me, the options were for s4-ribbonrow and zz17_TopNavigationMenuV4 . I have to change the hover,focus,and active properties.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out, for me, the ID's are s4-ribbonrow and zz17_TopNavigationMenuV4 . I had to change the hover,focus,and active properties.

```
#s4-ribbonrow a:hover,
#s4-ribbonrow a:focus,
#s4-ribbonrow a:active,
#zz17_TopNavigationMenuV4 a:hover,
#zz17_TopNavigationMenuV4 a:focus,
#zz17_TopNavigationMenuV4 a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
}


#s4-ribbonrow *,
#s4-ribbonrow *:before,
#s4-ribbonrow *:after,
#zz17_TopNavigationMenuV4 *,
#zz17_TopNavigationMenuV4 *:before,
#zz17_TopNavigationMenuV4 *:after,
*[class*='ms-core-menu'],
*[class*='ms-dlg'],
*[class*='ms-dlg']:before,
*[class*='ms-dlg']:after,
*[class*='ms-cui'],
*[class*='ms-cui']:before,
*[class*='ms-cui']:after,
*[class*='ms-cui'] *,
*[class*='ms-cui'] *:before,
*[class*='ms-cui'] *:after,
*[class*='ms-dlg'] *,
*[class*='ms-dlg'] *:before,
*[class*='ms-dlg'] *:after,
*[class*='ms-webpart'] * {
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
```